# Mapreduce - reducer class results not correct

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an Adcampaign driver, mapper and reducer classes. First two classes run great. The reducer class also runs fine but the results are not correct. This is a sample project I downloaded from internet to practice mapreduce program.

brief description of this program:
Problem statement:

For this article, let’s pretend that we are running an online advertising company. We run advertising campaigns for clients (like Pepsi, Sony) and the ads are displayed on popular websites such as news sites (CNN, Fox) and social media sites (Facebook). To track how well an advertising campaign is doing, we keep track of the ads we serve and ads that users click.

Scenario

Here is the sequence of events:
1.  We serve the ad to the user
2.  If the ad appears on users browser, aka user saw the ad. We track this event as VIEWED_EVENT
3.  If user clicks on the ad, we track this event as CLICKED_EVENT

sample data:

```
293868800864,319248,1,flickr.com,12 
 1293868801728,625828,1,npr.org,19 
 1293868802592,522177,2,wikipedia.org,16 
 1293868803456,535052,2,cnn.com,20 
 1293868804320,287430,2,sfgate.com,2 
 1293868805184,616809,2,sfgate.com,1 
 1293868806048,704032,1,nytimes.com,7 
 1293868806912,631825,2,amazon.com,11 
 1293868807776,610228,2,npr.org,6 
 1293868808640,454108,2,twitter.com,18 

Input Log files format and description:
Log Files: The log files are in the following format: 
times- tamp, user_id, view/click, domain, campaign_id. 
E.g: 1262332801728, 899523, 1, npr.org, 19
◾timestamp : unix time stamp in milliseconds 
◾user_id : each user has a unique id
◾action_id : 1=view, 2=click
◾domain : which domain the ad was served
◾campaign_id: identifies the campaign the ad was part of
```

Expected ouput from reducer was:
campaignid, total views, total clicks
Example:

12, 3,2
13,100,23
14, 23,12

I looked at the logs of Mapper. The output is good. But the final output from Reducer is not good.

Reducer class:

```
  public class AdcampaignReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text>
{

    //  Key/value : IntWritable/List of IntWritables for every campaign, we are getting all actions for that 
    //  campaign as an iterable list. We are iterating through action_ids and calculating views and click 
    //  Once we are done calculating, we write out the results. This is possible because all actions for a campaign are grouped and sent to one reducer. 

    //Text k= new Text(); 

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> results, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
   { 

        int campaign = key.get();
        //k = key.get();

        int clicks = 0;
        int views = 0;

        for(IntWritable i:results)
        {
                int action = i.get();
                if (action ==1)
                    views = views+1;
                else if (action == 2)
                    clicks = clicks + 1;


        }

        String statistics = "Total Clicks =" +clicks + "and Views =" + views;

        context.write(new IntWritable(campaign), new Text(statistics));


    }

}
```

Mapper class:

```
  public class AdcampaignMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {  

     private long numRecords = 0; 

     @Override
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text record, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


         String[] tokens = record.toString().split(",");

         if (tokens.length !=5)
         {
             System.out.println("*** invalid record  : " + record);

         }

         String actionStr = tokens[2];
         String campaignStr = tokens[4];     


         try{

             //System.out.println("during parseint"); //used to debug 
             System.out.println("actionStr =" + actionStr + "and campaign str = " + campaignStr);

             int actionid = Integer.parseInt(actionStr.trim());                      
             int campaignid = Integer.parseInt(campaignStr.trim());


             //System.out.println("during intwritable"); //used to debug
             IntWritable outputKeyFromMapper = new IntWritable(actionid);
             IntWritable outputValueFromMapper = new IntWritable(campaignid);


             context.write(outputKeyFromMapper, outputValueFromMapper);

         }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("*** there is exception"); 
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         }

         numRecords = numRecords+1;


     }



}
```

Driver program:

```
 public class Adcampaign {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.println("Usage: MaxClosePrice <input path> <output path>");
                System.exit(-1);
            }


            //reads the default configuration of cluster from the configuration xml files
            // https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-a-configuration-class-and-object-in-Hadoop-MapReduce-code

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();


            //Initializing the job with the default configuration of the cluster          

            Job job = new Job(conf, "Adcampaign");

            //first argument is job itself
            //second argument is location of the input dataset
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

            //first argument is the job itself
            //second argument is the location of the output path        
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));        


            //Defining input Format class which is responsible to parse the dataset into a key value pair   
            //Configuring the input/output path from the filesystem into the job
            // InputFormat is responsible for 3 main tasks.
            //      a. Validate inputs - meaning the dataset exists in the location specified.
            //      b. Split up the input files into logical input splits. Each input split will be assigned a mapper.
            //      c. Recordreader implementation to extract logical records

            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

            //Defining output Format class which is responsible to parse the final key-value output from MR framework to a text file into the hard disk    
            //OutputFomat does 2 mains things
            //  a. Validate output specifications. Like if the output directory already exists? If the directory exist, it will throw an error.
            //  b. Recordwriter implementation to write output files of the job
            //Hadoop comes with several output format implemenations.

            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            //Assigning the driver class name           
            job.setJarByClass(Adcampaign.class);

            //Defining the mapper class name            
            job.setMapperClass(AdcampaignMapper.class);

            //Defining the Reducer class name
            job.setReducerClass(AdcampaignReducer.class);

            //setting the second argument as a path in a path variable           
            Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

            //deleting the output path automatically from hdfs so that we don't have delete it explicitly            
            outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);

            job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            ///exiting the job only if the flag value becomes false

            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);


     }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `reducer output not good` can you share the few lines from output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the output as per the campaign_id. So the Campaign_id shud be key from the mapper code. And then in the reducer code, you will check whether its a view or a click.

```
     String actionStr = tokens[2];
     String campaignStr = tokens[4];     

     int actionid = Integer.parseInt(actionStr.trim());                      
     int campaignid = Integer.parseInt(campaignStr.trim());

     IntWritable outputKeyFromMapper = new IntWritable(actionid);
     IntWritable outputValueFromMapper = new IntWritable(campaignid);

    Here outputKeyFromMapper should be campaignid as the sorting will be done on campaignid.
```

PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF IT HELPS.

Comment: Ishan, will try and let u know

Comment: Thanks much Ishan.

Answer (score 0):

1. The output key from your mapper should be campaignid and value should be actionid
2. If you want to count number of records in mapper use [counters](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Counter)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapper and reducer looks fine.
Add below lines to your Driver class and give a try:

```
        job.setOutputKeyClass( IntWritable.class );
        job.setOutputValueClass( Text.class );
```

Comment: Will try and let you know Mahendra in 10 hoours